# Is there a way I could use cv::Mat data while destroying the cv::Mat holding it?

Tags: opencv

It's certainly a strange question but I would like to use data from a `cv::Mat` object OpenCV computed in a custom object that only needs a pointer from it.

It's like:

```
void func(const cv::Mat& a, void* pa) {
   cv::Mat b = a;
   b /= 256;
   pa = b.data;
   // b is destoyed but I still want to use the data
}
```

OpenCV handles smart pointers, but I don't know the library too well, is there a way to add a reference to the data pointer somehow?
`memcpy` is the option used right now.

Comment: You can create a `cv::Mat` header for an external data array (i.e. one that the `cv::Mat` won't be an owner of, meaning you need to handle its creation and lifetime yourself). https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a

Comment: since "a" is still present, it doesnt matter whether b will be destroyed, since the data will not be released until "a" and all other possible references will be destroyed. This is because cv::Mat share pixel memory in a reference counting mechanism. If you are not sure whether the data might be released you'll have to copy it.

Comment: I'm more familiar with DLib matrix expression implementation and I think OpenCV does the same. But the equal sign is the assignment rule so I am not sure the data I need i.e. b will be kept as there isn't any relationship left between a and b. I'm not sure about that though. The solution @DanMašek gives seems simple to do I will try that :)